# What's the easiest way to ignore one row of data when creating a histogram in R?

Tags: r, histogram

I have this csv with 4000+ entries and I am trying to create a histogram of one of the variables. Because of the way the data was collected, there was a possibility that if data was uncollectable for that entry, it was coded as a period (.). I still want to create a histogram and just ignore that specific entry.

What would be the best or easiest way to go about this?

I tried making it so that the histogram would only use the data for every entry except the one with the period by doing

```
newlist <- data1$var[1:3722]+data1$var[3724:4282]
```

where 3723 is the entry with the period, but R said that + is not meaningful for factors. I'm not sure if I went about this the right way, my intention was to create a vector or list or table conjoining those two subsets above into one bigger list called newlist.

Comment: Using a negative index will remove a row: `data1$var[-3723]`.

Comment: Sweet, thanks @MatthewDrury. But when I do that and view the newlist, it still says that '.' is a level, how can I remove it as a level now that its frequency is 0?

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is deeper that you realize.  When R read in the data and saw the lone `.` it interpreted that column as a factor (categorical variable).

You need to either convert the factor back to a numeric variable (this is [FAQ 7.10](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f)) or reread the data forcing it to read that column as numeric, if you are using `read.table` or one of the functions that calls `read.table` then you can set the `colClasses` argument to specify a numeric column.

Once the column of data is a numeric variable then a negative subscript or `!is.na` will work (or some functions will automatically ignore the missing value).